# Laravel Stored Procedure Insert/Select/Statement not working

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXEC SP_Account_Save_Registration ?,?,?,?' at line 1 (Connection: mysql, SQL: EXEC SP_Account_Save_Registration 1234567890,5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99,jREDACTED@gmail.com,09100069
```

This the error that I got when I was trying to call a stored procedure with parameter.
This is the stored procedure I'm trying to execute in laravel (10)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_Account_Save_Registration`(
    IN `xBadgeNumber` int,
    IN `xPassword` TEXT,
    IN `xEmail` text,
    IN `xMobile` VARCHAR(11)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    DECLARE IsAlreadyRegistered INT;
    SET IsAlreadyRegistered = 0;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO IsAlreadyRegistered FROM personnel_tbl WHERE badgenumber=xBadgeNumber;
    
    IF IsAlreadyRegistered > 0 THEN
        SET IsAlreadyRegistered =2;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO personnel_tbl(badgenumber, passwordx, emailadd, mobilenumber)
        VALUES(xBadgeNumber, xPassword, xEmail, xMobile);
        SET IsAlreadyRegistered =3;     
    END IF;
    SELECT IsAlreadyRegistered;
END
```

Basically this should return a value of 2 when the badgenumber is already in the database and returns 3 if the insert was successful.

This is how I call or run the stored procedure

```
    $result = DB::select('EXEC SP_Account_Save_Registration ?,?,?,?', [
                $arr['badge'],
                $arr['password'],
                $arr['email'],
                $arr['mobile']
   ]);
   dd($result);
```

I tried this too

```
$result = DB::select('EXEC SP_Account_Save_Registration(?,?,?,?)', [
                    $arr['badge'],
                    $arr['password'],
                    $arr['email'],
                    $arr['mobile']
       ]);
       dd($result);
```

I tried "EXEC/CALL SP_Account_Save_Registration(?,?,?,?)" but still not working.
I always get errors like

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXEC SP_Account_Save_Registration ?,?,?,?' at line 1
```

I also tried using DB::Statement and DB::Insert
What is wrong? Also if I tried directly calling the SP into Mysql Query box and add the parameters it works perfectly.

Comment: It should be `CALL SP...` not `EXEC SP...`

Answer (score 0):

I find what is wrong and this is thanks to @user1191247. It should be CALL instead of EXEC.

```
$result = DB::select('CALL SP_Account_Save_Registration(?,?,?,?)', [
            $arr['badge'],
            $arr['password'],
            $arr['email'],
            $arr['mobile']
        ]);
```

The above script works. I stated I used the CALL method but what happens is that I forgot to enclose the question marks ?,?,?,? and that cause the error.